# Growing a graph over a collection of (x,y) points

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

Problem:

Given a set of 2D points in a plane, find a set of edges *E* that minimizes both average trip time between any two points and the size of *E*: ie, by associating a cost *r* with each unit of trip time and a cost *e* per edge in the set.

I'm sure that there's a set of algorithms that deal with this problem, but I can't seem to find the right search term. I've considered starting with a complete graph and pruning, but I can't think of an efficient way to calculate the damage done by removing an edge. Any suggestions? Approximate ('good-enough') solutions welcome.

Let me know if my statement of the problem can be improved or clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some work in the literature on [spanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_spanner), which is related to what you describe (the main difference is that spanners control the maximum stretch, while you're concerned with the average). Chew's construction ("There is a planar graph almost as good as the complete graph", SoCG '86) gives an O(1)-approximation for your problem, since the triangulation has less than three times as many edges as a spanning tree (lower bound on the optimum, since the graph must be connected) and adjusts each Euclidean distance by a factor of at most sqrt(10) (hence the sqrt(10) times the average for the optimum).

Comment: And, in case anyone is wondering, the case of minimizing the dilation (ratio of path distance : straight-line distance) over n nodes with m edges is NP-hard.